# Series expansion message with special functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, series-expansion

I am trying to expand the following expression in `alp,eps`. Since the expression involves `Hypergeometric2F1`, I am using **[HypExp](https://hypexp.hepforge.org/)**.

```
<<HypExp`
expr=(2^(1/2 + alp + 3 eps) \[Pi] Gamma[1 + alp + 2 eps] 
     Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 - eps, 1/2 + eps, 3/2 + alp + eps, 1/2] 
     Sec[eps \[Pi]])/(Gamma[1/2 + eps] Gamma[3/2 + alp + eps]) *
     (8 Gamma[alp/2]^2)/Gamma[alp]

 Normal[Series[expr,{alp,0,2},{eps,0,1}]]//Timing
```

This is showing the following message.

[image]

If I take the expression in this message and do a `FullSimplify` it is indeed `0`.
I am not entirely sure if this message is due to the external package. They say it changes the default `Series` expansion, as Mathematica can not do this by default in the presence of `Hypergeometric2F1`. My question is if Mathematica is doing some checks internally and whether this slows down the performance and is there any way to turn this off to speed up expansion? This is important when we ask for more terms in the expansion `{alp,0,2},{eps,0,3}` which is super slow.

A related observation: while doing this expansion, it shows the message in the first evaluation which is also very slow. If I re-evaluate the cell a second time, this message does not appear, and it is also fast (probably it stores temporarily the results from the first evaluation and provides the same while doing a second evaluation?).

`$Version`
*"12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"*

Comment: Works well in 13.3.1 on Windows 10 without `HypExp`. The result`//N` is `{17.6563, (
 100.531 + (278.731 + 248.05 alp - 211.477 alp^2 + 
     204.013 alp^3) eps)/alp`.

Comment: @user64494     Numerically it is fine. But here the expansion is being done analytically which the default Mathematica Series expansion can not handle.

Comment: Here is a part of the symbolic result `(1/alp)(32 \[Pi] - 
   16 Sqrt[2]
     eps (2 Sqrt[2] EulerGamma \[Pi] - 3 Sqrt[2] \[Pi] Log[2] + 
      Sqrt[2] \[Pi] PolyGamma[0, 1/2] + ...`

Comment: @user64494.     I believe Mathematica is giving the correct expansion as shown in the screenshot. My question is to speed up this expansion for higher orders. I checked that the messages it is generating are correct. Now whether this is taking most of the time for the evaluation.